# Можно ли подключить компилятор C к приложению React Native?

Tags: c, компиляция, react-native

Проблема в том, что я хочу написать мобильное приложение на React Native для изучения языка C. Во время обучения я хочу показать примеры кода и его результат. Я пытался что-то найти в интернете, но не нашел нечего подбного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код Вы можете показывать в любом подходящем поле ввода/просто отформатировать красиво. А вот исполнять код можно через апи онлайн компилятора, к примеру http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ (само апи описано здесь https://docs.google.com/document/d/18md3rLdgD9f5Wro3i7YYopJBFb_6MPCO8-0ihtxHoyM/edit )

Там же прям есть на javascript

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", "http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/compile", false);
http.send(JSON.stringify({ "cmd": "g++ main.cpp && ./a.out", "src": "int main() { throw 1; }" }));
alert(http.response);
```